# Mongodb and Ruby gem - Check if record exists

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I've a simple Ruby script (no rails, sinatra etc.) that uses the Mongo gem to insert records into my DB as part of a Redis/Resque worker.

Upon occasion instead of doing a fresh insert I'd like to update a counter field on an existing record. I can do this handily enough with rails/mysql. What's the quickest way of doing this in pure Ruby with Mongodb?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby client library for MongoDB is very convenient and easy to use. So, to update a document in MongoDB, use something similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'mongo'

database = Mongo::Connection.new.db("yourdatabasename")

# get the document
x = database.find({"_id" => "12312132"})

# change the document
x["count"] = (x["count"] || 0) + 1

# update it in mongodb
database["collection"].update("_id" => "thecollectionid", x)
```

You might want to check out the [manual for updating](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) documents in MongoDB as well.

Comment: thanks evnu - this will definitely handle the counter update - perfect. I guess if the initial .find returns nil I can just enter into a new insert statement.

Comment: Yes, or you could use "upsert", which only updates if a document already exists or inserts when the document is missing. The manual explains the option that you have to pass to `update`.

Comment: If two processes try to increment the counter at the same time the second could overwrite the first. Might be worth looking at `findAndModify` with `$inc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to envu's direction I went with upsert in the end. here is an example snippet of how to use it the Ruby client:

```
    link_id = @globallinks.update(
      {
        ":url" => "http://somevalue.com"
      }, 
      {
        '$inc' => {":totalcount" => 1},
        '$set' => {":timelastseen" => Time.now}
      }, 
      {
        :upsert=>true
      }
    )
```